# Reduce repeated elements in a list

Tags: java

To compact in a new list without repeated elements, there may be null elements. I need help .

I have this error "Tester Error (Individual Delivery 4): the method returns []instead of [1] when invoked with [1]".

```
public <E> PositionList<E> compactar (Iterable<E> lista) 
{

    if(lista == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }// if      

    PositionList<E> newLista = new NodePositionList<E>();   
    Iterator<E>iterator = lista.iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()) 
    {
        if(eqNull(iterator,iterator.next())) {          
            newLista.addLast(iterator.next());
            }//if   
    }//while 
    return newLista;
}//compactar
```

//-------------assistant--------------------------------------------------------------

```
public static boolean eqNull (Object o1, Object o2)
{
    return o1 == o2 || o1!= null && o1.equals(o2);
    }// de eqNUll
}//  Operacioncompactar
```

Answer (score 1):

Not clear if you want to remove all dupes or just remove nulls. These remove dupes.

```
List<Comparable> l = ...; // The source list
List<Comparable> nl = new ArrayList<>(); // New list without dupes
Collections.sort(l);
Comparable last = UUIDs.randomUUID().toString(); // This one will never be in our source list
for (Comparable c: l) {
  if (!Objects.equal(c, last)) { // Or some other null-safe equals function
    nl.add(c);
  }
  last = c;
}
```

Running time O(nlogn). Elements in list of course need to implement a sensible `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

```
Set<?> set = new HashSet<String>(); // Track "seen"
List<?> l = ...; // Original list
List<?> nl = new ArrayList<>(); // New list without dupes
for (Object o: l) {
  if (!set.contains(o)) {
    nl.add(o);
  }
  set.add(o);
}
```

Running time is O(n), since hashset is constant lookup time. Or simpler:

```
Set<?> set = new HashSet<String>(); // Will be collection without dupes
List<?> l = ...; // Original list
for (Object o: l) {
  set.add(o); // Rely on set semantics to remove dupes
}
List<?> nl = new ArrayList<>(set);
```

Of course the objects in the list must implement a sensible `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 0):

With java 8, you can use Stream distinct to solve that.

The sample code as below.  Hope it will help you.

```
// input data
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add("A");
a.add("A");
a.add("A");
a.add(null);
a.add(null);
Iterator source = a.iterator();
Iterable<String> iterable = () -> source;
// logic code
Iterator temp = StreamSupport
        .stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList()).iterator();
Iterable result = () -> temp;

// verify result
StreamSupport
        .stream(result.spliterator(), false)
        .forEach(System.out::println)
```

;